# Tiling (repeating) image on Windows Phone 7.5 background

Tags: tiles, windows-phone-7

I need to repeat or tile a single image (size 9x9) across the Windows Phone 7.5 background.

How can this be done? I haven't found anything using Bing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF you normally would do it with a tiled `Grid.Background` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502346/dont-scale-imagebrush-while-resizing-repeat-it). But in WP7 this unfortunately is not possible. So the only ways of achieving this are writing something yourself or using a component.

One component is presented [in this blog post](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/633). It is basically a panel filling itself with the same image over and over again. At the end of the article there is a download link. Download the zip, unzip it and add `TilePanel.cs` to your project.

Then you can use it as follows in your XAML:

```xml
<local:TilePanel x:Name="pnlTile" TileWidth="62" TileHeight="62">
    <local:TilePanel.Image>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="ApplicationIcon.png" />
    </local:TilePanel.Image>
</local:TilePanel>
```

Don't forget to add the namespace:

```xml
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WiredPrairie.Controls"
```

The panel will be filled with the image specified in your XAML. Adjust image and size as needed.

Comment: Thats really great. Why I cannot think like you people?. Thank you very much.